# Big Query: ST_GeogFromText failed: Unexpected 'geometry' at position 0

Tags: sql, google-big-query

I'm pretty new to the GIS field, so might be ignoring something obvious here.

I'm trying to match Mlab speed test data (each record had lat long attribute) with map of administrative boundaries of Jamaica (uploaded as csv, last column is wkt).

```
SELECT 
    date,
    ROUND(avg(a.MeanThroughputMbps),3) as Mbps, 
    ROUND(APPROX_QUANTILES(a.MeanThroughputMbps, 100) [SAFE_ORDINAL(50)],3) AS download_MED,
    ROUND(max(a.MeanThroughputMbps),3) as maxMbps,
    ROUND(min(a.MeanThroughputMbps),3) as minMbps,
    count(a.MeanThroughputMbps) as number_speed_tests,
    ROUND(avg(a.MinRTT),3) as latency,
    count(client.Network.ASNumber) as number_ISP,
    string_field_3
FROM `measurement-lab.ndt.unified_downloads` as unified_downloads
JOIN `atlas-323422.Jamaica_boundaries.JAM_boundaries` as geo
ON ST_Within(ST_GeogPoint(client.Geo.Longitude, client.Geo.Latitude),(ST_GEOGFROMTEXT(geo.string_field_6, make_valid => TRUE)))
WHERE date >= "2021-06-01" and client.Geo.CountryCode = "JAM" 
group by string_field_3, date
```

Getting the following error:

```
ST_GeogFromText failed: Unexpected 'geometry' at position 0.
```

I did similar operations with other countries, same source for shapefiles, same query.

Jamaica table:
[image]

Comment: look at your data content, search for one whose `string_field_6` starts with the word geometry (maybe the csv header got inserted as a record?) or is null

Comment: Yup, that was the one, thanks:)